# How to display image with differrent size in storyboard using size class?

Tags: storyboard, autolayout

I want to display image in storyboard, but it's have different size for iPhone5,6,6+.
How to use size classes to set?

Comment: NOTE : You can not design UI on the basis of device type by iPhone5,6,6+ using size classes as it define the size not device, you can design such that what constraint should be apply in compact height or compact width.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure on what you're meaning, but you can easily use the UIImageView element that comes with iOS to test out images in your storyboard. You can also easily use auto layout. To access auto layout, there are 3 buttons at the bottom of the screen. Here is an example.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Example, Image's size like 640x40 for iphone4/5/5s,750x40 for iphone6,1242x60 for iphone6 plus.So how can I use it in storyboard?